# Why does cythons in-place division of numpy arrays use conversion to python floats?

Tags: numpy, cython

I tried to normalize a vector stored as numpy array, but `cython -a` shows unexpected conversions to Python values in this code.

Minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
cimport cython
cimport numpy as np

@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.boundscheck(False)
cdef vec_diff(np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] vec1, double m):
    vec1/=m
    return vec1
```

Cython 0.29.6 run with the `-a` option generates the following code for the line `vec1/=m`:

```
  __pyx_t_1 = PyFloat_FromDouble(__pyx_v_m); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) __PYX_ERR(0, 8, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_1);
  __pyx_t_2 = __Pyx_PyNumber_InPlaceDivide(((PyObject *)__pyx_v_vec1), __pyx_t_1); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) __PYX_ERR(0, 8, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_2);
  __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_1 = 0;
  if (!(likely(((__pyx_t_2) == Py_None) || likely(__Pyx_TypeTest(__pyx_t_2, __pyx_ptype_5numpy_ndarray))))) __PYX_ERR(0, 8, __pyx_L1_error)
  __pyx_t_3 = ((PyArrayObject *)__pyx_t_2);
  {
    __Pyx_BufFmt_StackElem __pyx_stack[1];
    __Pyx_SafeReleaseBuffer(&__pyx_pybuffernd_vec1.rcbuffer->pybuffer);
    __pyx_t_4 = __Pyx_GetBufferAndValidate(&__pyx_pybuffernd_vec1.rcbuffer->pybuffer, (PyObject*)__pyx_t_3, &__Pyx_TypeInfo_double, PyBUF_FORMAT| PyBUF_STRIDES, 1, 0, __pyx_stack);
    if (unlikely(__pyx_t_4 < 0)) {
      PyErr_Fetch(&__pyx_t_5, &__pyx_t_6, &__pyx_t_7);
      if (unlikely(__Pyx_GetBufferAndValidate(&__pyx_pybuffernd_vec1.rcbuffer->pybuffer, (PyObject*)__pyx_v_vec1, &__Pyx_TypeInfo_double, PyBUF_FORMAT| PyBUF_STRIDES, 1, 0, __pyx_stack) == -1)) {
        Py_XDECREF(__pyx_t_5); Py_XDECREF(__pyx_t_6); Py_XDECREF(__pyx_t_7);
        __Pyx_RaiseBufferFallbackError();
      } else {
        PyErr_Restore(__pyx_t_5, __pyx_t_6, __pyx_t_7);
      }
      __pyx_t_5 = __pyx_t_6 = __pyx_t_7 = 0;
    }
    __pyx_pybuffernd_vec1.diminfo[0].strides = __pyx_pybuffernd_vec1.rcbuffer->pybuffer.strides[0]; __pyx_pybuffernd_vec1.diminfo[0].shape = __pyx_pybuffernd_vec1.rcbuffer->pybuffer.shape[0];
    if (unlikely(__pyx_t_4 < 0)) __PYX_ERR(0, 8, __pyx_L1_error)
  }
  __pyx_t_3 = 0;
  __Pyx_DECREF_SET(__pyx_v_vec1, ((PyArrayObject *)__pyx_t_2));
  __pyx_t_2 = 0;
```

where the first line `__pyx_t_1 = PyFloat_FromDouble(__pyx_v_m);` has `PyFloat_FromDouble` highlighted in dark red.

Given that I have told cython that the array contains double values, why does it have to convert to a python float?

Note: Memoryviews do not support the /= operation (would require a loop)

Answer (score 1):

Because this isn't something that Cython does anything special for or optimises at all. All it's doing is calling `__Pyx_PyNumber_InPlaceDivide` on the Numpy array, which calls the Numpy array's `__idiv__` operator.

Since it's calling a Python operator it needs to pass a Python object as the second argument, and hence it needs to convert your double to a Python float.

The Numpy `__idiv__` operator is almost certainly written in C so likely to be pretty fast (although there is a little overhead calling it) so there's not a lot of value in Cython doing anything except delegating to Numpy's code.

---

Memoryviews don't define the whole-array operators (they're just ways to access memory so don't make any claims about meaningful mathematical operations) and hence the fact that it doesn't work is consistent with how Cython deals with these operators.